# Selecting first tab with jQuery. Only way that works gives Firebug error

Tags: jquery, firebug

I am trying to programmatically select the first tab with jQuery.

This works

```
$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected', 0).trigger();
```

but gives the following Firebug error associated with the jQuery code.

```
TypeError: c is undefined
```

Putting anything, even '', within the trigger() parentheses prevents any errors but causes the call to not have the desired effect.

Comment: Why are you calling .trigger?

Comment: Looks like your are using `variable c` somewhere without defining it..

Comment: @Sushanth-- it's more likely that c is a minified jQuery variable, which is the text passed to trigger().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If just

```
  $( '#tabs' ).tabs('select', 0);
```

doesn't work, you can just simulate a click on the first tab when you want this behaviour.  You just need to find a selector that will get the first tab.

```
$('first tab selector').click();
```

Comment: I tried $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected', 0).click(); and it did not appear to do anything.

Comment: You don't need to add .click(), just $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected', 0)  itself should be enough to select the tab.  Did you try that?

Comment: Try $( '#tabs' ).tabs('select', 0);

Comment: Who is Peter?  It seems to work in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/eN7Z5/2/  At this point you should put your code in a jsfiddle so we can see what the code looks like.

Comment: $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected', 0).tabs("refresh");  Try this as well.  I'm shooting in the dark at this point.

Answer (score 0):

`selected` is not a valid `tabs` option - http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

I think you want to do it with `active` -

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
```